# How can I get what is in [b7]? Please help me get right Xpath

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Can someone please help me get the right data from this XML path?
The following array is an xml path called FIRST. How can I get what is in [b7]?

```
Array([0] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
      ( [@attributes] => Array 
          ( 
            [a1] => ENG 
            [a2] => 7F5         
            [a3] => 0 
            [a4] => 0 
          )

        [LINK] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
        ( 
        [@attributes] => Array 
            ( 
                [b1] => bla
                [b2] => bla - bla
                [b3] => 0 
                [b4] => 0 
                [b5] => bla
                [b6] => bla-bla 
                [b7] => 232323
                [b8] => 1 
                [b9] => bla-bla-bla
            )
        ) 
      )
 )
```

I've tried getting  the FIRST array with `$something = $value-> xpath('FIRST')` 
and it works but when I'm trying `$bla="{$something['0']['b7']}"` I get nothing back.

Any help??

Comment: Presenting your problem as XPath against **XML** rather than PHP/SimpleXML's internal representation of XML might get you more answers.

Comment: To put @kjhughes comment a different way: show us what the actual XML looks like, not the result of `print_r` after loading it with SimpleXML. The `print_r` view can be rather misleading. You might also like to play around with [these debug functions I wrote](https://github.com/imsop/simplexml_debug).

Comment: If I post the xml, I really don't think that there's going to be enough space for it here. It's really long.

Comment: @IreM Debugging often involves creating a minimal version of the problem; a small XML file with the relevant parts would have been one approach. You show a small segment in this `print_r`; you could paste just that part of the XML. From looking above, I think the non-XPath SimpleXML approach would be `$something[0]->LINK['b7']` - your attempt doesn't mention the `LINK` element at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example ([Demo](https://eval.in/58729)):

```
<?php
/**
 * How can I get what is in [b7]? Please help me get right Xpath
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/19502280/367456
 */

$xml = simplexml_load_string('<CONTENT><LINK b7="hey"/></CONTENT>');
var_dump($xml);

$b7 = (string)$xml->xpath('LINK/@b7')[0];
var_dump($b7);
```

Program Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["LINK"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["b7"]=>
      string(3) "hey"
    }
  }
}
string(3) "hey"
```